# Updating Structured Table Reference using Autofill VBA in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2013, excel-2016

I'm using a macro to populate the columns of a table with a set of formulas I populate (via the macro) into the first column of the table.

This line of code (simplified) autofills to the end of the table in Excel 2016.

`Range("B3").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B3:D3"), Type:=xlFillDefault`

I am using structured table references within my formulas to reference other cells within the table. When doing the autofill function these structured cell references automatically update like I'm expecting.

On Excel 2013 this doesn't work. The structured table references do not update column by column when the macro is run. They do update when a user manually clicks and drags the B3 cell to autofill to the rest of the table. It is just the structured references that aren't updating accordingly, the normal cell references are fine.

```
                            B           C           D
- Correct autofill:   3 [@Column 1] [@Column 2] [@Column 3]
- Incorrect autofill: 3 [@Column 1] [@Column 1] [@Column 1]
```

Here are some pictures of the table:

Table prior to macro
[image]

Correct - Table post macro
[image]

Correct - Table with values
[image]

Incorrect - Table post macro
[image]

Incorrect - Table with values
[image]

Comment: Why not loop through a range instead of using autofill to satisfy version restrictions?

Comment: @Mech, I was worried about performance issues mainly. Maybe I just naively assumed that Excel's built-in auto-fill would be faster, but I should probably check to see if the loop time would be acceptable. Still would like to know if it is just a bug in 2013 or something updated in 2016.